# How to retrieve user.uid data from Firebase in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have some doubts about Firebase in python (Pyrebase Library). The first doubt is if I can retrieve the data of the user.uid from firebase in python script because my database const of this **users/+user.uid+/.../**. And the other doubt is if I can listen to child live changes in Pyrebase, I know that it has the streaming method, but I don't know if I can obtain the path and the data of the exact child which change. Thank you for help.

Comment: I would recommend using the official library for this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python

Comment: After take a look of that library, I think that pyrebase is less complex, thank you @HristoStaykov